# Making a heatmap table from a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, heatmap

I have a Pandas Dataframe that I want to make a heatmap from. I see how I could make a heatmap using plotly/seaborn, but that doesn't generate what I am looking for. This image is more what I'm looking for.[image: Heatmap from excel]

This is really easy to do in excel, but I am not sure how to do it in Python.

Comment: What do you want your output to be? An Excel file? An image? Something else? If you want an image, what should it look like? You should be able to do this using plotly/seaborn.

Comment: Ultimately I want it to be a graph that looks like the reference image so that I can input it into a Dash dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You could use the style.background_gradient method from pandas with a colourmap ranging from red to green. Depending on the value, this will fill in the background of cells in the dataframe.

```
from  matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
cm=LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('rg',["r", "w", "g"], N=25)
display(df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm))
```

[Output_Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgrBu.png)